# Two div button position top and bottom how to let them position to left and right

Tags: html, css, vue.js

There is two button position top and bottom, how can I make them become left and right like the second image. I am using **floating vue** so the button will become a div is it possible to make them become left and right position? Sample here >>> [Test minimal example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-popover-iuyx3x?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:11-439)
[image: image 1][image: image2]

```
  <div>
    <VDropdown :triggers="['hover']" placement="top-start">
      <button>Test</button>
      <template #popper>
        <div style="padding: 1rem">Help Me</div>
      </template>
    </VDropdown>
    <VDropdown :triggers="['hover']">
      <button>Test 2</button>
      <template #popper>
        <div style="padding: 1rem">Hello t2</div>
      </template>
    </VDropdown>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a parent `div` (I can see you have one already) and add a style of `display: flex;` you can also add a style of `justify-content: center;` to keep the elements centered on the page.

Code:

```html
<div class="dropdowns" style="display: flex; justify-content:center;">
    <VDropdown :triggers="['hover', 'focus']" placement="top-start">
      <button>Test</button>
      <template #popper>
        <div style="padding: 1rem">Help Me</div>
      </template>
    </VDropdown>
    <VDropdown :triggers="['hover', 'focus']">
      <button>Test 2</button>
      <template #popper>
        <div style="padding: 1rem">Hello t2</div>
      </template>
    </VDropdown>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!